# How to start function in activity A after activity B finished?

Tags: android, android-activity

my app has 2 activities. The main activity is A. I call start B in A. (In B when user press Backbutton B's process will be killed by this code)

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

my question is, how do I start a function in A when B is finished?

Comment: No need to kill processes like that in a regular app. Any specific reason you're doing it? Calling `finish()` will automatically pop the activity that's on top of the stack (in your case the previous activity)

Comment: Read above comment and also http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html. This will help you to create logic how to call method after B finished'

Answer (score 7):

Start your activity B by Activity A

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.Class);
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

finish your activity B with

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent );       
finish();
```

now in ActivityA

```
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //Do your work here in ActivityA

  }
```

Comment: good answer, worked for me. can you explain what the 0 in startActivityForResult is for. and also what RESULT_OK does exactly?

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this `int pid = android.os.Process.myPid(); android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);` just use `finish();`. THis will help you to come back to the previous activity. As per your code, the application was completely killed.